# Is HTTPS sufficient to protect app/server communication?

Tags: tls, server

Scenario:

Adam has designed an iPad app that will be publicly distributed.  The app will communicate with Adam's server via https.  While the fact that this app communicates with this server isn't sensitive, the particulars of the communication between the app and the server are -- things that are trade secrets might be inferred by seeing that specific data that the app is requesting of and getting from the server.  Adam is worried that Eve may be able to see the plain-text communication between the app and the server when Adam's app is running on Eve's iPad, connected to Eve's wifi network.

If Eve is a highly competent individual or small company (but not necessarily the NSA/CIA/KGB/etc), can Eve accomplish the goal of seeing the communication between the app and the server under these circumstances if the only encryption is via https?  This assumes that Eve can fully manipulate her own wifi network and accept whatever fake certificates and ignore whatever warnings the iPad may offer.  (This is NOT about Eve seeing communication between Adam's server and the app on Brad's iPad when he's using Starbucks wifi -- we assume that Eve controls the device and the network here.)

If Eve is able to see such communication, would Adam be well advised to encrypt everything sent between the app and the server, or is this adding cost to his project for slight or no gains?

Comment: a bit unclear what you're asking, but you should expect that people who own the hardware will be able to see what the hardware is doing.

Comment: What's really going to bake your noodle is the realization that a reasonably competent individual isn't going to use an iPad to get at the data: Adam has no way to verify that the client is an iPad, or that the client is actually running his app in the first place.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I absolutely get that, although seeing what the API calls look like makes that attack happen much sooner than guessing what they look like -- so seeing the traffic over the https would be the first step of that attack.

Comment: @dandavis Expecting that Eve can "see what her hardware is doing" is awfully broad.  I don't think many individuals can watch memory being written and read on their device, although the NSA probably can.  OTOH, it's not too hard to see that my device is communicating over the internet.  The question is, where on that continuum does reading traffic encrypted with HTTPS fall -- when Eve controls both the device + the network?  Just above "anybody can..." or just below "only the NSA can..."?

Comment: If I control the device, it's trivial to read encrypted traffic, because I can subvert my own security (usually, by rooting the device or installing a proxy cert) (anybody can).  Emulators and debugging the device to view memory are also an option (may require a developer account).  On the other hand, there is no known attack that would let the NSA read data encrypted by an unknown certificate.  You're attempting to implement a form of DRM, which has failed for every game published - and people break these as a personal challenge.

Answer (score 4):

You should assume that any data sent to a device is fully visible to the owner of the device.

Trying to transfer content to a device without actually making it accessible to the device's owner is effectively what DRM attempts to accomplish, with only limited success.  After all, can you think of any video games that haven't been pirated?  DRM can make it **more difficult** for a device owner to access the content, but there is no way to make it impossible.

HTTPS in particular mainly protects against snooping from people in between the device and you server.  There are a variety of techniques and tools that can allow even someone with little computer skills to intercept HTTPS traffic on their own devices.

The next step of protection is to add public key pinning to your app.  This prevents a user from using an HTTPs proxy, which is the most common (and usually simplest) way of intercepting network traffic.  By using public key pinning you make it so that the device owner has to root their device and/or reverse engineer your app to remove the public key pinning requirement.

After that it gets much harder, and with less benefit.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Can you expend a little on the "variety of techniques and tools" that let one intercept HTTPS traffic on their own device?  Also, for one who is authoring an app to run on iOS, is encrypting the calls to and returns from the server as good as public key pinning (given that the only traffic of interest is between the app and a single server that the same author controls)?

Comment: @ConfusionTowers the simplest (but not only) way is by setting up the device with an HTTP(s) proxy and then installing the proxie's root certificate on the device.  For these purposes whether or not encrypting requests/responses yourself is better depends on how you actually do it. You have to store the encryption keys in the app and as soon as an attacker has it they can decrypt your traffic. Depending on how you store it, it may be easier for an attacker to steal it than break the public key pinning (which requires modifying the app)

Comment: Still, my main question is: do you really want to do either of these things? It is very hard to hide things from the client. The best solution is to only send them things that you are okay with them having.